# What is the proper way to login with feathers-authentication-local but store jwt in cookie?

Tags: feathersjs

What is the proper way to store jwt token in cookie with the latest feathers-authentication-client and feathers-authentication-local?

Couldn't find any documentation on it. Managed to get it works in localStorage with the following code but prefer to store it within cookies, like what feathers-authenticaion-oauth2 did.

```
const host = 'http://localhost:3030';
export const app = feathers()
  .configure(rest(host).superagent(superagent))
  .configure(feathers.hooks())
  .configure(auth({ 
    storage: localStorage,
    type: 'jwt',
  }));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing good but on the wrong documentation. Try this one https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/server.html.

The way you configure your auth is in legacy [pre-auk](https://legacy.docs.feathersjs.com/). Then feathers-authentication-client and feahters-authentication-local are in latest [auk](https://docs.feathersjs.com/).

Update: As for today April 24 2017, there is a npm package that keeps the old client libraries 0.x using auth local and socket.io compatible with auk style login 1.0+. [feathers-authentication-compatibility](https://github.com/MichaelErmer/feathers-authentication-compatibility)